# aws lambda with rds mysql DDL command not working

Tags: aws-lambda

I have created lambda function which is successfully connected to database when using DML command like

"Select" or "insert" but when i am try to "created database" or "create table" its return success but table or database not created into RDS .

in-short insert query insert records and select return same records so no issue in connection but create commands not working.

Followings are my lambda policy

[image]

```
 const mysql = require('mysql');

const con = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : process.env.RDS_HOSTNAME,
  user     : process.env.RDS_USERNAME,
  password : process.env.RDS_PASSWORD,
  port     : process.env.RDS_PORT,
    connectionLimit : 10,// max number of connections before your pool starts waiting for a release
    multipleStatements : true,// Prevent nested sql statements
    connectionLimit : 1000,
    connectTimeout  : 60 * 60 * 1000,
    acquireTimeout  : 60 * 60 * 1000,
    timeout         : 60 * 60 * 1000,
    debug    : true 
   // ,database:'testdb1'
});


exports.handler = async (event) => {

  con.query('CREATE DATABASE testdb1', function (err, result) {
    if (err){
          console.log("Error->"+err);
       throw err;
    }
  });

  return "Completed..."
};
```

Comment: Please post some code

Comment: The query has a callback, but the handler function not coded to wait for that. is it your real code or different.

Comment: thanks , it's working fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lambda should wait for queries to complete. Let's first fix that. After that, check if the lambda reports back any errors when trying to create the database.

```
const mysql = require('mysql');

const con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: process.env.RDS_HOSTNAME,
  user: process.env.RDS_USERNAME,
  password: process.env.RDS_PASSWORD,
  port: process.env.RDS_PORT,
  connectionLimit: 10,
  multipleStatements: true,// Prevent nested sql statements
  connectionLimit: 1000,
  connectTimeout: 60 * 60 * 1000,
  acquireTimeout: 60 * 60 * 1000,
  timeout: 60 * 60 * 1000,
  debug: true
  // ,database:'testdb1'
});

exports.handler = async (event) => {
  try {
    const data = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      con.connect(function (err) {
        if (err) {
          reject(err);
        }
        con.query('CREATE DATABASE testdb1', function (err, result) {
          if (err) {
            console.log("Error->" + err);
            reject(err);
          }
          resolve(result);
        });
      })
    });

    return {
      statusCode: 200,
      body: JSON.stringify(data)
    }

  } catch (err) {
    return {
      statusCode: 400,
      body: err.message
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Added the promise syntax. your code is correct, it should work.  my guess is, the user may not have permission to create the database. The lambda is not showing the permission errors because it's not waiting for the query execute to finish.

Comment: Also please adjust if there are any syntax errors. I haven't try to executed this code.